# Performance improvement for Dijkstra algorithm using heaps in python?

Tags: python, dijkstra, heap

Below is my implementation for Dijkstra's algorithm using heaps (for undirected graphs).

This works just fine for reasonably sized graphs however I am not satisfied by my code for recalculating greedy criterion of nodes connected to the newly explored node.

Here I iterate over all of the items in the heap which doesn't look like a good use of the data structure. Is there a better way to achieve this ?

*The `graph` is a dictionary which contains for each node (key) a list of nodes connected to it and the length of the edge.
`graph[v]` returns `[[w_1, l_1],...,[w_k, l_k]]` where there is an edge between `v` and `w_i` of length `l_i` for all `i`s between 1 and k. Sort of like an adjacency list.*

```
shortestPath = {1: 0}  # Length of the shortest pass from s (labelled 1) to v (v's label = key)


def createHeap():
    # Heap contains the greedy criterion for an edge and the label of it's head vertex
    heap = []
    for k, v in graph.items():
        if k in shortestPath:
            continue  # Ignoring starting vertex
        bestScore = 1000000
        for (w, length) in v:
            if w in shortestPath:
                greedyScore = shortestPath[w] + length
                if greedyScore < bestScore:
                    bestScore = greedyScore
        hq.heappush(heap, (bestScore, k))  # bestScore used as heap key
    return heap


def dijkstra():
    heap = createHeap()
    for _ in range(n - 1):  # For every vertex in graph (other than starting vertex 1)
        greedyScore, w = hq.heappop(heap)  # Next vertex to be processed
        shortestPath[w] = greedyScore
        for [v, length] in graph[w]:  # Finds the new crossing edges and re-evaluates greedy criterion
            if v not in shortestPath:
                for item in heap:  # better implementation ?
                    if item[1] == v:
                        oldScore = item[0]
                        heap.remove(item)
                        hq.heapify(heap)
                        newScore = min(oldScore, greedyScore + length)
                        hq.heappush(heap, (newScore, v))

dijsktra()
```

Comment: `if w in shortestPath:` in function `createHeap()` - I think `w in shortestPath` iff `w == 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several alternative implementations of Dijkstra's algorithm, but none of them need to iterate through the heap, nor remove arbitrary nodes from it, nor re-heapify it repeatedly. All those actions kill the performance benefit that a heap is intended to give.

I would also advise to avoid global variables. Instead pass what is needed as arguments, and let the function `dijkstra` *return* the results.

Here is one of the possible implementations you could use for your `graph` data structure:

```
def dijkstra(graph, start):
    distances = {}
    heap = [(0, start)]

    while heap:
        dist, node = hq.heappop(heap)
        if node in distances:
            continue  # Already encountered before
        # We know that this is the first time we encounter node.
        #   As we pull nodes in order of increasing distance, this 
        #   must be the node's shortest distance from the start node.
        distances[node] = dist
        for neighbor, weight in graph[node]:
            if neighbor not in distances:
                hq.heappush(heap, (dist + weight, neighbor))

    return distances
```

Example call:

```
graph = {
    "a": (("b", 8), ("c", 3), ("d", 6)),
    "b": (("a", 8), ("e", 5)),
    "c": (("a", 3), ("d", 2), ),
    "d": (("a", 6), ("c", 2), ("e", 5), ("g", 3)),
    "e": (("b", 5), ("d", 5), ("f", 5)),
    "f": (("e", 5), ("g", 3), ("h", 6)),
    "g": (("d", 3), ("f", 3), ("h", 4)),
    "h": (("g", 4), ("f", 6))
}

distances = dijkstra(graph, "a")

print(distances)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 0, 'c': 3, 'd': 5, 'b': 8, 'g': 8, 'e': 10, 'f': 11, 'h': 12}
```

Comment: Just wanted to note that this may put the same node in the heap several times, but that's fine because the of the `if node in distances:` check.

Comment: @joseville, yes, that is true. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Using_a_priority_queue) points to such algorithms as *"yet another alternative"*, and concludes: *"These alternatives can use entirely array-based priority queues without decrease-key functionality, which have been found to achieve even faster computing times in practice."*